# loop through array or list in variable steps

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to figure out how to loop through an array or list in variable steps.

So for example, if I have the following list...

```
a = [0,0,1,0,0,1,0]
```

...and want to use the following logic:

- Start at index 0
- If index two spots away is a 0, move two spots
- If index two spots away is a 1, move one spot

  However, I'm not quite clear how I can implement this logic as it seems like I can't change my index value I iterate through.

Why does this snippet still return values from 0-6 instead of 0,3,6?

```
for idx,val in enumerate(a):
        print(idx)
        idx+=3
```

Comment: check out the discussion section of https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/jumping-on-the-clouds/problem.

Comment: Use a while loop

Comment: @yatu sure you can.

Comment: Well, `range` objects happen to be immutable, so you can never modify a `range` object, in or outside a loop. However say, `iterable = [1,2,3]` you can modify `iterable` inside your for-loop if you want.

Comment: @yatu that isn't a `for` loop. That's a list comprehension. Two fundamentally different things. And for the record you *can* modify the iterable of a `for` loop, but it usually breaks things (though it is predictable and consistent)

Comment: Well yes @GreenCloakGuy true say a regular for loop, i did it to fit it in a comment but agreed its not the same

Comment: You can mess around with the iterable in a list-comprehension to, in messy ways for sure, given the lack of statements and only expressions. My point isn't that one *should*, only that one *can*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a `for` loop.

`for` loops in python are different than in C or Java. In those languages, a `for` loop has an *initial condition*, a *termination condition*, and an *increment* for each time the loop runs. Whereas in python, a `for` loop is more of a `for each` loop - you give it an iterable object, and it runs the code for every item in that iterable object.

Modifying the iterable object *while you're running through it* is a bad idea that can have difficult-to-predict repercussions and will usually break your code.

---

However, you can always use a `while` loop:

```
a = [0,0,1,0,0,1,0]
idx = 0

while(idx < len(a) - 2):
    print(idx)
    if a[idx + 2] == 0:
        idx += 2
    elif a[idx + 2] == 1:
        idx += 1
print(idx)
```

which produces the expected output

```
0 1 3 4 6
```

Or, if you change the increments to `3` and `2` respectively, rather than `2` and `1`,

```
0 2 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is pretty confusing, and I don't see *ANY* application for this, but here is how I understand your problem...

The reason is because you aren't actually returning the values, you're simply returning the index + 3, which is wrong to begin with. What you're trying to do is point to a new index of the array based on its value and return the index if it contains a value greater than 0.

You need to reference the index you want, check its value, then return the index which contains a value.

```
a = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
for i, v in enumerate(a):
   if i == 0:
      print(i)
      next
   if v == 0:
      next
   else
      print(i)
```

But let's be honest, this is extremely ugly and un-pythonic. Let's simply check for whether a[i] contains a value, and if so, return the index...

```
for i, v in enumerate(a):
   if v or i == 0:
      print(i)
```

The purpose of `if v or i == 0` is to check if v has a value, if so, print the index. OR if we are looking at the first element of i.

If you want to EXPLICITLY move the index by two, you must set your index at the start and use a while loop, since enumerate can't help you here and doesn't actually let you move the indicies...

```
a = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
i = 0
while i < len(a) - 1:   # -1 to avoid out of bounds error
   print(i)
   if a[i + 2] == 0:
      i += 2
   elif a[i + 2] == 1:
      i += 1
print(i)            # Final print statement for the last index at the end of the while loop
```

I want to impress upon you the fact that this solution does NOT scale with different or larger lists, which is why it isn't recommended. By simply checking for whether a value does or doesn't exist, you guarantee your accuracy.

You should simply return the index based upon whether or not it contains a value. Even for very large lists, this will be extremely fast, and will always scale, even for values greater than 1.

The only other reason I would see you would want to do this differently is if you're doing string-search algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that python refreshes the the variables each iteration. So at the end of the first run, idx would be 3 but then at the start of the second run, it gets reset to 1.

If you want to go through a loop by 3s, you can still use a for loop

```
for i in range(0,len(a),3):
  print(i)
```

If you want a dynamic iteration value, then you need to use a while loop.

```
i=0
while i<len(a):
  print(i)
  if(a[i]==0):
    i+=2
  else:
    i+=1
```

Comment: This doesn't check the element "two spots away". Also, you could end up trying to index an element outside of the range of the list.